# Marshal.Copy Throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, marshalling, dllimport, outofrangeexception

I'm trying to marshal data from managed memory in my C# application to an unmanaged memory location for use by a proprietary DLL.  The value is a float, but the DLL requires a pointer to a float.  In the constructor, the my idea was to assign unmanaged memory to the pointer, and then copy the passed-in float value to the unmanaged memory.

```
internal class MyInternalClass
{
    private static float[] fltArry;

    public struct MY_DLL_STRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr fltPtr;

        public MY_DLL_STRUCT(float flt)
        {
            MyInternalClass.fltArry = new float[] { flt };
            this.fltPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(float) * MyInternalClass.fltArry.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(MyInternalClass.fltArry, 0, this.fltPtr, sizeof(float) * MyInternalClass.fltArry.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

The sizes look good to me, but whenever the `Marshal.Copy` function is called an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does your unmanaged function actually take an array of floats, or just a pointer to a single float that it uses to modify/output that one single value? If the latter, you can make life much simpler by declaring the parameter as `ref float` or `out float` (depending on whether it reads the input or not). A single, statically sized array of one element in a struct can be declared with `[MarshalAs(Unmanagedtype.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]` with no need to explicitly allocate unmanaged memory. Only if you really have more than one value do things get more complicated.

Comment: @JeroenMostert This looks interesting.  Yes, it's just a pointer to a single float value. 
 Would you mind posting an answer with an example of how it should be used?  I'm not sure where the `MarshalAs` statement you suggest would be placed.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the appropriate interop code is without seeing the unmanaged function/struct declaration. The code you've shown here does nothing with any unmanaged resources, it just puts a single `float` in an unmanaged block of memory. What do you do with the resulting `fltPtr`?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Haha, I wish I knew!  All I'm given is the header and compiled DLL.

Comment: The (C) header is all that's needed; that's what I meant with "unmanaged declaration". Presumably there's a struct pointer it accepts and/or a function you call. The signature of that function/the declaration of that `struct` is what's appropriate here. If all you know is that you have to cough up an `IntPtr` and that must be a field in a class somewhere then this is still overkill (and how are you planning to deallocate the memory?) but not completely unreasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last parameter to `Marshal.Copy` is the [number of elements to copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy?view=netframework-4.8#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_Copy_System_Single___System_Int32_System_IntPtr_System_Int32_).

I suspect you should use `1` (or `MyInternalClass.fltArry.Length`) rather than `sizeof(float) * MyInternalClass.fltArry.Length`. You are passing a value too large, thus:

> **Exceptions**
>
> ArgumentOutOfRangeException - startIndex and length are not
>   valid.